# LINKERD: Unable to build docker image from linkerd

Tags: docker, linkerd

https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd#docker
From the instruction on Readme, I have executed the following commands,

> ; linkerd/docker ;namerd/docker

I get the following exception,

```
[info] Done packaging.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last linkerd/bundle:docker for the full output.
[error] (linkerd/bundle:docker) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/home/shaikk/linkerd/linkerd/target/docker"): error=2, No such file or directory
[error] Total time: 284 s, completed Mar 6, 2017 9:13:49 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `No such file or directory` error message is referring to the `docker` binary itself. Can you try running `which docker` to see if it's in your path? If it's not there, you can install it using the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/#platform-support-matrix

Comment: Hey you are right, there was a problem with the way I have installed the docker, thank you.
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/